# Merge return blank data

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Within my master data frame , I tried to  merge some-other-data frame locally, but the result comes back as blanks 
master data frame ( data)

```
MTTR    WhiteList   DateOfOutage    Vendor  Tech    Sites
25  FALSE   1-Aug   ERICSSON    2G  UPP5975
18  FALSE   2-Aug   ZTE 3G  UPP5975
17733   FALSE   3-Aug   ERICSSON    3G  UPP5806
17730   FALSE   4-Aug   ERICSSON    3G  UPP5806
3419    FALSE   1-Aug   ZTE 2G  UPP2347
10  FALSE   2-Aug   ZTE 2G  UPP2347
4   FALSE   3-Aug   ZTE 2G  UPP2347
1   FALSE   4-Aug   ZTE 2G  UPP2347
1   FALSE   1-Aug   ZTE 2G  UPP2347
1   FALSE   2-Aug   ZTE 2G  UPP2326
5   FALSE   3-Aug   ZTE 2G  UPP2326
3   FALSE   4-Aug   ZTE 2G  UPP2326
```

second data ( cont)

```
Sites   Tech    id  DateOfOutage    Contribution
UPP5975 2G  5975    8/1/2019    0.0000 %
UPP5975 3G  5975    8/2/2019    0.0000 %
UPP5806 3G  5806    8/3/2019    0.0000 %
UPP5806 3G  5806    8/4/2019    0.0000 %
UPP2347 2G  2347    8/1/2019    0.0000 %
UPP2347 2G  2347    8/2/2019    0.0000 %
UPP2347 2G  2347    8/3/2019    0.0249 %
UPP2347 2G  2347    8/4/2019    0.0000 %
UPP2347 2G  2347    8/1/2019    0.0000 %
UPP2326 2G  2326    8/2/2019    0.0000 %
UPP2326 2G  2326    8/3/2019    0.0000 %
UPP2326 2G  2326    8/4/2019    0.0000 %
```

the result

---

```
data= pd.merge(data, cont, how='left', on=['DateOfOutage','Tech','Sites'])

MTTR    WhiteList   DateOfOutage    Vendor  Tech    Sites   id  Contribution
25  FALSE   2019-08-01 00:00:00 ERICSSON    2G  UPP5975 5975    0.0000 %
18  FALSE   2019-08-02 00:00:00 ZTE 3G  UPP5975 5975    0.0000 %
17733   FALSE   2019-08-03 00:00:00 ERICSSON    3G  UPP5806 5806    0.0000 %
17730   FALSE   2019-08-04 00:00:00 ERICSSON    3G  UPP5806 5806    0.0000 %
3419    FALSE   2019-08-01 00:00:00 ZTE 2G  UPP2347 2347    0.0000 %
10  FALSE   2019-08-02 00:00:00 ZTE 2G  UPP2347 2347    0.0000 %
4   FALSE   2019-08-03 00:00:00 ZTE 2G  UPP2347 2347    0.0249 %
1   FALSE   2019-08-04 00:00:00 ZTE 2G  UPP2347 2347    0.0000 %
1   FALSE   2019-08-01 00:00:00 ZTE 2G  UPP2347 2347    0.0000 %
1   FALSE   2019-08-02 00:00:00 ZTE 2G  UPP2326 2326    0.0000 %
5   FALSE   2019-08-03 00:00:00 ZTE 2G  UPP2326 2326    0.0000 %
3   FALSE   2019-08-04 00:00:00 ZTE 2G  UPP2326 2326    0.0000 %
```

Comment: Hi  bakr sayed, welcome on SO. Please edit your post using markdown and share your `df`s with `df.head().to_dict()`. You might find interesting reading about [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](/help/mcve)

Comment: `Date of Outage` field in two dfs seems to be in different format. You could preprocess using `datetime` package and then do you merge operation